# i am trying to find a commercial solution for the social website login from my application

Tags: java, twitter, authentication

i am trying to find a commercial solution for the social website login from my application. When i am trying to connect to janrain server, m getting connection refused.

```
public class AuthInfo extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // The user's browser will POST a token to your "token_url" you specified to have them
        // redirected to after the auth process:
        String token = request.getParameter("token");
        // Do a request to the Janrain API with the token we just received.
        // see http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/api/auth_info/
        // You may wish to make this HTTP request with e.g. Apache HttpClient instead.
        URL url = new URL("https://rpxnow.com/api/v2/auth_info");
        String params = String.format("apiKey=%s&token=%s",
            URLEncoder.encode(getServletConfig().getInitParameter("apiKey"), "UTF-8"),
            URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8")
        );
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        connection.connect();//** Failing here **

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8" );
        writer.write(params);
        writer.close();
```

Comment: there are many reasons for this exception. in my practice if you are sure that URL is right and web server isn't down, the most often is proxy problem. but on the basis of available data, it is nothing more than an attempt to guess

Comment: Thanks for replying though... 
URL is right and webserver is up as u suggested.

Comment: and what about proxy? should your app send request via it?

Answer (score 0):

You need the name of your Social Login (Engage) application in the URL. You can get the correct URL from the "Application Settings" section of the Janrain dashboard.

So, `https://rpxnow.com/api/v2/auth_info` should be something like `https://YOUR_APP_NAME.rpxnow.com/api/v2/auth_info`.